# Client disconnected, but server don't see it

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, exception, tcp

so i was making a Tcp Server, when i got a problem while a client is disconnecting. Exception is being throwed, but it looks like that server don't see it. And it don't remove the disconnected client from list. Here is code:

```
    public void Read(IAsyncResult ar, TcpClient PL)
    {
        try
        {
            {
                BytesRead[PL] = PL.GetStream().EndRead(ar);
            }
            if (BytesRead[PL] < 1)
            {
                throw new SocketException();

            }
            else
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    packets++; break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            if ((x.Message.Contains("Client") && x.Message.Contains("Disconnected")) || x is SocketException || x is EndOfStreamException || x is IOException)  //|| x.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(IOException))
            {
               throw;
            }
            else
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

It occurs when client closes program or when it's killed by task manager

Here is where method `Read` has been used.

```
    private void HandleClient(object client)
    {

        TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream();
        while (true)
        {

            try
            {
                while ((true))
                {
                    {
                        

                        try
                        {

                            
                        }
                        catch (SocketException ex)
                        {
                            if ((ex.Message.Contains("Client") && ex.Message.Contains("Disconnected")) || ex is SocketException)
                            {
                                throw;
                            }
                        }
                        try
                        {
         
                            {
                                
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
            
                if (((ex.Message.Contains("Client") && ex.Message.Contains("Disconnected"))) || ex is SocketException )
                {
                    clients.Remove(tcpClient);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the `TcpListener` Initialization

```
    public void Server1()
    {
        timer = new Timer(new TimerCallback(MultipleCheck), null, 0, 500);
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("25.75.22.56"), 29339);
        listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
        listenThread.Start();
    }
```

And here is method where it accepts the `TcpClient`

```
    private void ListenForClients()
    {

        listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            System.Console.Title = "Server : " + clients.Count.ToString();
            if (!LineStarted)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine("Server started on port 29339");
                LineStarted = true;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Connection Request");
            TcpClient client =  listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            if (client.Connected)
            {
                clients.Add(client);
                System.Console.WriteLine("New Client Connected");
                
                //if (threads.ContainsKey(client))
                {
                    threads[client].Start(client);
                }
                counter++;
                
            }

            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the exception and stack trace? Which line is causing the trouble?

Comment: `BytesRead[PL] = PL.GetStream().EndRead(ar);` this one

Comment: Can you show the code ,when you used the `void Read(IAsyncResult ar, TcpClient PL)` method,and Initialize `TcpClient`.

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: How long it usually takes for somebody to answer the question?

Comment: _"How long it usually takes for somebody to answer the question?"_ -- that depends on the question. For straightforward, well-written questions that include a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, an answer might be provided relatively quickly. Often in less than an hour, and in many cases, at least less than half a day or so. A question like yours? You might never see an answer posted to it, and even if one is posted, it may or may not wind up being all that useful to you.

Comment: The server will only detect a dropped client if it tries to actively read/write data to it. You ought to implement some kind of keep-alive that tries to send a little piece of data to the server every `x` seconds. If an exception occurs when the client sends it you know the connection has been dropped; if the server doesn't get a keep-alive message after `y` seconds the client connection is assumed to be dropped and therefore you discard it.

Comment: Also do instruct Visual Studio to throw _ALL_ exceptions while debugging, that is, even handled exceptions (how to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx). You have a little different way of using `try/catch` statements which might result in some exceptions getting swallowed. When debugging it's best to ignore/remove all `try/catch`es so that you'll always get notified when something goes wrong.

Comment: Keep in mind that your code is even harder for us to understand than what it is for you, which makes it even harder for us to diagnose a problem. Like @PeterDuniho said an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is preferred to make it easier for us to help you. By _**recreating**_ a smaller version of your code, you might sometimes even find the problem yourself and don't have to ask a question about it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the `threads[tcpClient].Abort();` put try instruction

```
try
{
//Removing Client from list and notifying connected users about disconnected 
//client from list
}
catch
{
}
//And after Abort the thread to avoid the exception of thread aborting being
//thrown too early
threads[tcpClient].Abort();
threads.Remove(tcpClient);
```